# Random walk converges in distribution to standard normal

Tags: probability-theory

If $S_{n} = X_{1}+\dots+X_{n}$, where each $X_{i}$ is $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability, it is claimed that $\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable. Is it possible to deduce from that alone that $\frac{S_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$ also converges to a standard normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 
$$
\frac{S_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}=\underbrace{\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}}_{\stackrel{d}\to N(0,1)}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}}_{\to 1}+\underbrace{\frac{X_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}}_{\stackrel{d}\to 0},
$$
then use [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).

Comment: What is preventing us from saying that $\frac{S_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}} = \frac{X_{1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}} + \frac{X_{2}}{\sqrt{2n+1}} + \dots + \frac{X_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, and that each term converges in distribution to 0, therefore the whole thing converges in distribution to zero?

Comment: In other words, we essentially have the sum of $\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}$, which converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$, and $\frac{X_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, which converges in distribution to 0. And we are saying that the sum of these converges in distribution to the sum of the limits? Right?

Comment: It only works for definite sums; like a sum of two variables, or three variables, but not $n$ variables. Your second comment is correct, but you have to be careful. The limit of the sum is the sum of the limits _as long as one of the limits is constant_ (i.e. nonrandom). See the [Slutsky's theorem article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) to see why this condition is necessary.